# How to use SFTP connection with key file using C# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh-keys, pem

I have a C# .NET project, where am trying to open an SFTP connection to a server and put a file to the server.

I have SFTP *hostname*, *username* and *key file* (.pem file).
I do not have a *password* here.

Please help me with something to use SFTP in C# and .Net.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Probably every SFTP/SSH library supports public key authentication.

For example:

- [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) ([NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET)):

  ```
  var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\some\path\key.pem");
  var client = new SftpClient("example.com", "username", new[] { privateKey });
  client.Connect();
  ```

  If the private key is encrypted:

  ```
  var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\some\path\key.pem", "passphrase");
  ```
- [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) ([NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP/)):

  ```
  SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
  {
      Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
      HostName = "example.com",
      UserName = "username",
      SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 ...=",
      SshPrivateKeyPath = @"C:\some\path\key.ppk",
  };

  using (Session session = new Session())
  {
      session.Open(sessionOptions);

      // Your code
  }
  ```

  WinSCP needs the key converted to PPK format (You can use WinSCP GUI for that, or PuTTYgen). Also note that WinSCP verifies the SSH host key (`SshHostKeyFingerprint`). SSH.NET fails to do that by default, what is a security flaw.

  If the private key is encrypted, add [`PrivateKeyPassphrase`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#privatekeypassphrase) or [`SecurePrivateKeyPassphrase`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#secureprivatekeypassphrase).

  WinSCP GUI can [generate a code template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code).

  *(I'm the author of the library)*

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. The code provided by Martin certainly helped me but, it was missing a couple settings for my needs.

I needed to add a Port Number and a Pass Phrase to fully automate my solution. So code ends up like:

```
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                PortNumber = port,
                HostName = host,
                UserName = username,
                PrivateKeyPassphrase = passphrase,
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = fingerprint,
                SshPrivateKeyPath = privatekeyfile
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

Nuget> SSH.Net

```
       using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(new PasswordConnectionInfo("URL", "Username", "Password")))
        {
            client.Connect();

            string Serverfile = "";
            string Localfile = "";

            using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(Localfile))
            {
                client.DownloadFile(Serverfile, stream);
            }

            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**